# how to inspect element JavaScript on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I can inspect element my HTML on IE 11 but I cant seem to see my JavaScript file. For some reason my HTML5 game works on all browsers but IE11 and I want to fix that. Can someone please tell me how to use the DOM explorer(IE11 inspect element) to navigate to the JavaScript? I see it in the debugger but just not the Dom explorer so please help me before I go insane.

Comment: How would finding where the JS is in the DOM (even assuming it is in the DOM in the first place) help you figure out why it isn't working? That's what the debugger is for.

Comment: I will like to edit the JavaScript in the browser. Cant edit JavaScript in the debugger right?

Comment: Maybe it *is not* in the DOM. How did you load it? Can you show us the source? There are so many ways to execute scripts so that they show up in the debugger but not in the DOM.

Comment: can you give me a example or source to this info? I don't feel like uploading the source to my game.

Comment: FYI : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx